# Python unicode errors while writing to file

Tags: python, string, file-io, unicode, encoding

I'm using Python 2.7 to parse through a bunch of webpages and get the content from them, but the webpages include characters like "" and ', which are both somehow converted to ‚Äô.  This gives me a file with content that looks like this (excluding the quotes): "I think it‚Äôs important..."

The strings print out fine in the terminal using the `print()` method, but I can't seem to get that same effect using `print >> file, string` or `file.write(string)`.  Obviously this is an encoding issue, but I've searched with no success to find a way around this.  I'm opening the file like this: `file = codecs.open("file.txt","w+", encoding='utf-8')` and I'm using BeautifulSoup4's `getText()` method to assign the strings their values.  Is there some way to solve this?

Comment: Can you give us the link to that page?

Comment: Downvote for lack of reproducible code. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add below lines code in start of function, which will solve your problem.

```
        import sys
        reload(sys)
        sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```

Comment: This is a nasty fix-all hack. You'll quickly find that it masks other issues as you've used a sledgehammer to crack a nut

Comment: This probably fixed either your input or output where encoding hasn't been defined

Answer (score 0):

You can try to write it out as:

```
file.write(output_str.encode('utf-8', 'ignore'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Enforce utf8 encoding at the beginning of your code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
myfile = open('./myfile.txt', 'w')
myfile.write("I think it's important to be able to see all characters")
myfile.write("\nIt woùld be Ñìçè to see foreign letters as well")
myfile.write("\n")
myfile.close()
```

Comment: That just means that non-ASCII in your **source code** can be interpreted correctly. It really has any meaning when you're creating Unicode objects, which you're not

Answer (score 0):

Some source code would have been good.

BeautifulSoup usually does a good job at guessing the encoding of the given string:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4

>>> print bs4("\x80", "html.parser").text # Windows 1252
€

>>> print bs4("\xe2\x82\xac", "html.parser").text # UTF-8
€
```

Except when it can't:

```
>>> print bs4("\xa4", "html.parser").text # ISO-8859-15
¤
```

Therefore, you should pass BeautifulSoup a decoded Unicode instead:

```
>>> print bs4("\xa4".decode("iso-8859-15"), "html.parser").text # ISO-8859-15
€
```

This means that your input data needs to be decoded correctly. Open input files with `io.open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8")` (or appropriate encoding).

If pulling remote web sites, inspect the "Content-type" header or use Requests, which returns decoded Unicode in the `.text` attribute on the response object.

When writing to a file, you have the right idea by using codecs module. io module is the newer way to do this.

When you put all of this together, you'll write data that has been correctly encoded.